# How do I put the Appendix along with the PDF on one page?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, pdf, appendix, tocstyle

I would like to put the appendix in PDF format on one page at the top of which is written "Appendix 1" - it also needs to be in the table of contents without a number according to my university's guidelines - no method I have found (Separate file with /appendix, pasting the following code into main.tex) works.

main.tex:

```
\chapter*{Appendix A}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A}
\includepdf[scale=0.9]{Praca/appendix/appenix_1.pdf}
```

I also tried to create a separate file appendix.tex:

```
\appendix
\label{appendix:Appendix_A}
\includepdf[pages=1,offset=0 0, pagecommand={\chapter*{Appendix A}\label{Appendix A_1}\thispagestyle{plain}}
]{Praca/appendix/appendix_1.pdf}
```

But then in the text I can not refer to them as Appendix A, but random numbers appear, for example, 10.

[image: Random number after adding ref]

The latter option is almost good, because in the table of contents it displays correctly, but the number instead of the appendix name spoils everything.

I will have to add several attachments - do all of them have to be in a separate file?

Edit:
I managed to get it to work using:

```
  \{addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A}

 \{includepdf[scale=1,pages=1,pagecommand=chapter*{Appendix A}{app:Appendix_A}]{Work/appendix/appendixa.pdf}
```

But in the table of contents it shows one page too few and takes you to the incorrect page. Specifically, my Appendix A is on page 40 and in the table of contents it displays as page 39 where there is other content, and clicking on "Appendix A" in the table of contents takes you to one page too soon (i.e., to 39 instead of 40).

**EDIT**

In the name of the answer, where I am not able to add a photo shows it here:

[image: What it looks like:]

[image: What it should look like (with the name omitted):]

Edit:
I'm using [this](https://github.com/splaw1k/PG_LaTeX_Templates) template, in which the additions are resolved in this way:

```
\chapter*{Dodatek A}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A}
\includepdf{meta/example-image.pdf}
```

In the text, the appendix should look like this: as shown in Appendix A - where Appendix A is a hyperlink to the appendix at the end of the entire document (under the list of sources).

Currently, as recommended by @cfr, my additions look like this:

```
    \{addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Addition B}

    \{includepdf[scale=1,pages=1,pagecommand=chapter*{Appendix B - Printed circuit board assembly diagram}}]{work/additions/assembly.pdf}
```

And in the text they are presented as numbers, instead of the hyperlink I mentioned:

[image: Wrong reference (10 instead of Appendix B)]

Number where it should be "Appendix B", the text in Polish says " Schematic diagram is also included in 10" but should be "Schematic diagram is also included in Appendix B"

The code for this looks as follows:

```
Idea diagram is also included in~ref{app:appendix_b}.


It is worth mentioning that clicking on this 10 takes you to the appropriate place in the file where the pdf file is added by \includegraphics

My cls file:

    \newif\ifnostrict

\DeclareOption{strict}{\nostrictfalse }
\DeclareOption{nostrict}{\nostricttrue }
\ProcessOptions \relax

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Pobranie ustawieñ podstawowej klasy dokumentu - klasa report
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\LoadClass[
  a4paper,                      % format A4
  10pt,                         % rozmiar czcionki
  twoside,                      % druk jednostronny %ALBO ONESIDE!!!!!!!!!!!!
  notitlepage,                  % brak strony tytu³owej
  openright,                    % orientacja otwierania dokumentu
]{report}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Ustawienie domylnego jêzyka i kodowania
%--------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{polski}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Podstawowa czcionka - Helvetica (Zamiennik dla czcionki Arial)
%--------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Ustawienie interlinii
%--------------------------------------------------------------------

\linespread{1.3} % 1.3 odpowiada interlinii 1.5, 1.6 dla interlinii 2

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Ustawienie marginesów
%--------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[%
    margin=2.5cm,
    a4paper,
    bindingoffset=1cm
]{geometry}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Ustawienia akapitów
%--------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{indentfirst}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.9cm}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Numeracja stron 
%--------------------------------------------------------------------

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont\thepage}%
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
}

\pagestyle{plain}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Ustawienia nag³ówków
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage[explicit, clearempty]{titlesec}

% konfiguracja dla tytu³u rozdzia³u
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]                    
{\bfseries\fontsize{12pt}{24pt}\selectfont}
{\thechapter.\quad}
{0pt}
{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{6pt}

% konfiguracja dla tytu³u podrozdzia³u
\titleformat{\section}                          
{\fontsize{11pt}{22pt}\selectfont\bfseries\itshape}
{\thesection.\quad}
{0pt}
{#1}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{6pt}{6pt}

% konfiruacja dla pod-podrozdzia³ów
\titleformat{\subsection}                      
{\normalfont\itshape}
{\thesubsection.\quad}
{0pt}
{#1}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{6pt}{6pt}

% subsubsection
\titleformat{\subsubsection}                 
{\normalfont\itshape}
{\thesubsubsection.\quad}
{0pt}
{#1}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{12pt}{6pt}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Spis tresci - konfiguracja 
%--------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{titletoc}
%\usepackage{titletoc}
%\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{2em}

% ustawienia dla rozdzia³ów w spisie treci
\titlecontents{chapter}
    [0em] % no indentation
    {}
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{1.4em}} 
    {\hspace*{-1em}}                         
    {\dotfill\contentspage}
    
% ustawienia dla podrozdzia³ów w spisie treci
\titlecontents{section}
    [2em] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 0.5em
    {}
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{2em}}  
    {\hspace*{-2.3em}}                          
    {\dotfill\contentspage}

% ustawienia dla pod-podrozdzia³ów w spisie treci
\titlecontents{subsection}
    [5em] % ie, 2em (section) + 3em
    {}
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{3em}}  
    {\hspace*{-2.3em}}                        
    {\dotfill\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsubsection}
    [9em] % ie, 2em (section) + 3em
    {}
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{4em}}  %three digits and three dots
    {\hspace*{-2.3em}}                          % !
    {\dotfill\contentspage}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Konfiguracja list numerowanych i nienumerowanych
%--------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{enumitem}

\setenumerate{
    topsep=0pt,
    nolistsep,
    noitemsep,
    }
\setenumerate[1]{label=\arabic*.}  
\setenumerate[2]{label=\alph*)}     

\setitemize{
    topsep=0pt,
    noitemsep,
    nolistsep,
}


%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Konfiguracja prezentacji aparatu matematycznego
%--------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{amsthm}


%%%%%%%% srodowiska twierdzeñ %%%%%%%%
\newtheoremstyle{SPPG_th1}% hname
{10pt plus5pt minus2pt}% hSpace above
{10pt plus3pt}% hSpace below
{}% hBody font
{}% hIndent amount
{\bfseries}% hTheorem head font
{.}% hPunctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% hSpace after theorem head
{}% hTheorem head spec 
\theoremstyle{SPPG_th1}

\newtheorem{definicja}{Definicja}[chapter]
\newtheorem{twierdzenie}[definicja]{Twierdzenie}
\newtheorem{lemat}[definicja]{Lemat}
\newtheorem{fakt}[definicja]{Fakt}
\newtheorem{wniosek}[definicja]{Wniosek}
\newtheorem{przyklad}[definicja]{Przyk³ad}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Konfiguracja obrazków oraz tabel
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{subfig}
\RequirePackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage[skip=2pt]{caption}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}
\RequirePackage{multicol} % do sk³adu w dwóch kolumnach
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{wrapfig}
\RequirePackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}   


% Modyfikacja podpisu rysunków i tabel  (zmiana na Rys. X niepogrubione)
% Separator po identyfikatorze rysunku
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Rys.}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{dot}{. }
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=centering,labelfont=md} % centrowanie podpisu rysunku
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=dot} % kropka jako separator, bez pogrubiania
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=dot} % kropka jako separator, bez pogrubiania

% Zmniejszenie czcionki oraz interlinii w podpisach
\captionsetup{font={small,stretch=1.0}}

\setlength{\intextsep}{3mm}      % odleg³oci separacji tekstu od rysunków/tabel
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{3mm}


%--------------------------------------------------------------------
% Dodatkowe ustawienia
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
 %???
\renewcommand\bibname{Wykaz literatury} % Zamiana na tytu³ "Wykaz literatury"

% Zmiana na tytu³ "Wykaz rysunków"
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Wykaz rysunków}

% Zmiana na tytu³ "Wykaz tabel"
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Wykaz tabel}

% Brak "wdów" i "sierot"
\widowpenalty10000
\clubpenalty10000

% Nazwy rozdzia³ów w Spisie treci WIELKIMI LITERAMI
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                         {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}%
                       \else
                       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Welcome! Please note this site operates in English. I've added a translation from Google Translate, but please check it, if you can. It is probably going to be hard to help you without a minimal compilable example and more information about your document. `\includepdf` always starts a new page, so either you have to hack what it does or you should use `\includegraphics`. But this is a very non-standard way to include an appendix. Why are you producing it first as PDF and then including it, rather than just writing it as part of your document?

Comment: Depending on your class and any packages, there are various ways to configure the numbering, formatting and toc lines for appendices and other supplementary document elements.

Comment: The PDF file is an exported PCB assembly schematic from a CAD program - when submitting a paper to the university, I also have to provide these files separately, where the PCB is 1:1 scale, and the default file in which these schematics are exported is the PDF.

Comment: Probably you want `\includegraphics` rather than `\includepdf`. The current answer makes it a background image, but then you need to allow room for the appendix heading.

Comment: @cfr In the post edit I added infrormation on how I (almost) managed to get it to work, the problem is only the page number in the table of contents reduced by one. 


As for scaling, I thought about that too but then the sizes won't be 1:1 with the original PCB :/

Comment: You are adding it to the contents on the previous page. `\includegraphics` is the easier way to go here. That's orthogonal to any question of scaling. If your PDF has multiple pages, I'd use `\includepdf` with a custom command which wraps everything you need done. This means defining a command which redefines itself on the first page. If your PDF has only a single page, you could use that approach (with no need for redefinition), but I'd probably just use `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @cfr Adding the file works fine in terms of the table of contents using the \includegraph, but ~ref{app:appendixk_c} continues to give the number 10 instead of the letter C and I am unable to set the image inside the appendix correctly. I'm adding the pictures as a reply because posting them here doesn't work :(

Comment: Please *edit* your question rather than posting information in the answer space. But what you really need to do is provide the code for a complete minimal document which demonstrates the problem so people can actually help you. I've said what I generally do in these cases and, yes, you have to adjust things. You have to do that either way. But nobody can tell you how to adapt code you've not shared. We need a test document. Use e.g. `example-image` etc. (package `mwe` but doesn't need loading) so people can reproduce.

Comment: Hey @cfr , thanks for your advice - I edited the post where I tried to add as much information as possible - sorry for the confusion, this is the first time I've ever used Latex and it's a very different approach for me than Word

Comment: Can you make a small compilable example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` which we can use to reproduce the issue? Because how you are setting things up affects what will work here. Which class you're using and any relevant configuration makes a difference to what will work without causing further problems.

Comment: @cfr I'm honestly not sure I understand what you mean. There will be no problem with dependencies looking at what template I am using? The hyperlink to it is in the latest edit and my attempts to write a new example file on the fly didn't work, but if it's necessary I'll keep trying.

Comment: In this case, I think a minimal document using that class would work as an example. Do you *have* to use that template? I ask because (1) such templates generally cause problems and this one doesn't look to be an exception and (2) this particular template is doing something which is really going to make the appendices a headache. The definition of chapter headings uses a conditional which doesn't exist in the base class it is using.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a template from my university and every thesis must be based on it or created based on the template in Word.

Comment: Is https://github.com/splaw1k/PG_LaTeX_Templates/blob/master/Praca/szablonPG.cls the class you're using? I don't understand why you don't get an error for `\chapter{}`.

Comment: Yes this is the file I'm using, I've added some changes to it (mostly visual) that's why I added the whole CLS file to the post.

Comment: With your version I get an immediate error. `! LaTeX Error: Command \contentsname already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
`

Comment: It's probably best if somebody who likes `titlesec` and `titletoc` helps you. I avoid `titlesec` like the plague.

Comment: Hey @cfr, thanks for all the time you took to help. I will keep looking but I really appreciate your dedication :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}` to overlap a full page image with other stuff.  However, `\chapter*` will not produce a label.  You need `\refstepcounter{chapter}` for that.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\appendix
\chapter*{Appendix A}
\refstepcounter{chapter}\label{AppA}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix \thechapter}

\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0pt,-\paperheight)% relative to upper left corner
  {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{example-image}}}
\newpage
\end{document}
```