# How to fix page numbering and page references in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf, pdfpages, include

Hey in my table of contents appendixes display incorrectly

[image: Wrong numbering]

The chapter "List of tables" is actually on page 40, but "Appendix A" (In the picture named as "Dodatek A", "Dodatek" is translating from Polish means "Appendix") is on page 41 - the hyperlink to Appendix A also leads to page 40, but Appendix B displays correctly and the hyperlink to it also works correctly - so does Appendix C on page 43.

The main file of the project includes:

```
\{input{work/chapters/additions}.
```

and the "additions" file contains:

```
    \{addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dodatek A}

    \{includepdf[scale=1,pages=1,pagecommand=chapter*{Appendix A - Circuit Schematic}}}

    {{Appendix/Appendices/Schemat_calculus.pdf}}



    \{addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DodatekB}}

    \‗includepdf[scale=1,pages=1,pagecommand=chapter*{Appendix B - Printed Circuit Board Paths}}]{Work/app:appendix_B}}



    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DodatekC}

    \includepdf[scale=0.9,pages=1,pagecommand=chapter*{Appendix C - Printed Circuit Board Assembly Schematic}}]{Work/appendix/mounting.pdf}
```

I also tried adding \phantomsection both in the main file before \input and in the additions file before each of the \addcontentsline commands but that didn't help.

If it's important: The appendix files are to be at the end of the work, do not contain the chapter number and each file is actually just a pdf file.

Comment: I think I know how to fix this, but without a MWE I can't test it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you for your answer - it's quite a big project and I don't know how to prepare MWE for it without removing significant elements, I use this template: https://github.com/splaw1k/PG_LaTeX_Templates/tree/master/Praca because it's a template with the requirements of my university - if it's not enough I will try to create MWE, although I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/702882/how-do-i-put-the-appendix-along-with-the-pdf-on-one-page.

Comment: You need the write to the `toc` file to be done as part of the `pagecommand`. `\includepdf` always starts a new page. If you add the line to the toc and then do `\includepdf`, whatever is included will be on the next page. Alternatively, use `\includegraphics`, which doesn't start a new page. I think there was some reason you didn't want to do this, but for single page PDFs it is more straightforward. Where you want to include multiple pages, things get more complex. I do pretty much precisely this for multipage-PDF inclusion and, even so, you just need a dynamic command.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Why have you got `\{` rather than `\addcontentsline` etc.?

Comment: `\addcontentsline` is best added *after* the `\chapter*` to which it applies.  When placed before an `\include` instruction, it will be held until the included file has been processed, but the page number will be wrong.  Move the `\addcontents...` command inside the included file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I can't add the command inside the add-on because they are PDF files

Answer (score 0):

The following requires the packages `nextpage` and `hyperref`. You may not need these, depending on your configuration. It will work for single or multi-page PDFs, if you substitute any required page style for `plain` and/or `empty`.

```
\NewDocumentCommand\includepdfspecial { O{}mm }{%
  \def\makeregstyle{\thispagestyle{plain}}% substitute name of page style here
  \def\makethisstyle{\thispagestyle{empty}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}}%
  \def\makedynstyle{\makethisstyle\global\let\makethisstyle\makeregstyle}%
  \clearpage\cleartooddpage[\thispagestyle{empty}]%
  \phantomsection
  \includepdf[
        pagecommand={\makedynstyle},
        #1,
    ]{#3}%
}
```

Usage: `\includepdfspecial[<options>]{<title for toc>}{<filename>}`. `<options>` can be any options you want to pass `\includepdf`, `<title for toc>` is the title to be added to the contents and `<filename>` is the name of the file you'd usually give `\includepdf`.

Note that although I use something very like this, this specific code is untested due to the lack of anything to test with.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different way to create numberless chapters.  OTOH, I couldn't get `pagecommand` to actually print things, much less `\cleardoublepage`.

To get the PDF page to fit below the chapter title, I trimmed 2in off the top and bottom, then aligned it to the bottom of the page.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
{\tableofcontents}% note group

\chapter{Normal Chapter}

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\numberline\string\@gobble}% turn off numbers in the ;middle of the TOC
\let\@makechapterhead\@makeschapterhead
\makeatother

\chapter{Numberless chapter}
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0pt,-\paperheight)%
  {\includegraphics[page=1,clip,trim=0pt 2in 0pt 2in]{test5}}}% replace tsst5 with your own PDF

\end{document}
```

Comment: It almost works - I mean the file adds well to the table of contents and to the whole file but in the table of contents, however, it has the number of the next chapter and I would like it not to be there. Additionally - how can I refer to this appendix in the text? As a hyperlink?

Comment: You can add a `\label` like any other chapter, but `\ref` will return the chapter number (or letter).   `\nameref` will return the title.  If you are using a package like titletoc, you should use it to supress the number.  `\@makechapterhead` will not be used.

Comment: If I understood correctly I should do something like this in appendix.tex:
\{makeatletter
\%addtocontents{toc}{%makeatletter}.
%makeatletter{toc}.
\makeatother
\`chapter*{Appendix A}
\}AddToHookNext{shipout/background}.
 {includegraphics[page=1,clip,trim=0pt 0in 0pt 0in]{Work/appendix/appendix_a.pdf}}
And in the main file:
\{phantomsection
%\phantomsection
\input{Praca/rozdzialy/appendix.tex}
\end{document}
\{{document}}

Comment: But it doesn't work - if I uncomment the \let and remove the * at the \chapter then appendix A appears in toc but numbered, if I remove I do exactly the version as in the code shown then nothing shows in toc but the file is added correctly - i.e. the PDF displays at the end of the document

Comment: I think I have succeeded in getting it to work

Answer (score 0):

```
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\numberline\string\@gobble}
\let\@makechapterhead\@makeschapterhead
\makeatother
\chapter*{Appendix A}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A}
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0pt,-\paperheight){\includegraphics[page=1,clip,trim=0pt 0in 0pt 0in]{Work/Appendix/Appendix_A.pdf}}}

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\numberline\string\@gobble}
\let\@makechapterhead\@makeschapterhead
\makeatother
\chapter*{Appendix B}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix B}
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0pt,-\paperheight){\includegraphics[page=1,clip,trim=0pt 0in 0pt 0in]{Work/Appendix/Appendix_B.pdf}}}
```